# Sikuli slash character not recognised (European keyboard)

Tags: python, sikuli, sikuli-x

I am using Sikuli and my script returns an error because of the following line.

```
type("06/01/2017" + Key.ENTER)
```

On the screen, I see that the script types 06 and then it stops. The problem is the slash.
The error seems to be related to me using a non-US keyboard. I found some tips online like using type("&") or type("7", KEY_SHIFT) instead. However, it does not work.

This is the error message I get:

```
type("06/01/2017"+Key.ENTER) at sun.awt.windows.WRobotPeer.keyPress(Native Method)
at java.awt.Robot.keyPress(Unknown Source)
at org.sikuli.script.RobotDesktop.doKeyPress(RobotDesktop.java:98)
at org.sikuli.script.RobotDesktop.doType(RobotDesktop.java:361)
at org.sikuli.script.RobotDesktop.typeChar(RobotDesktop.java:375)
at org.sikuli.script.Region.keyin(Region.java:4429)
at org.sikuli.script.Region.type(Region.java:4299)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang

.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key code
```

Thank you in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `paste()` for entering the text and then `type()` separately for pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.